# How much time passes between Jim first meeting Pam and their wedding?

Tags: the-office

In the american version of The Office, at the time of their wedding, Jim says that he had to wait for a long long time. Is there any indication to know exactly how much time has passed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this timeline](http://theoffice.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_The_Office), Jim started to work in Dunder Mifflin in 2001 (about 4 years prior to season 1). This is supported by Ryan's claim in [Dwight's Speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight%27s_Speech) (late season 2) that Jim has been working there for 5 years. And in [Launch Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_Party) (season 4), he tells Pam he liked her on his first day, when she showed him to his desk. So, since they marry in late 2009, we can assume he waited for about **8 years** to marry her.

Answer (score -2):

A lloonnnggggg time. Jim had a girlfriend for a while and Pam went through an engagement before they finally ended up together.

So basically from Season 1 (2005) until their marriage in Season 6 (2010).

Comment: Actually, probably *before* season 1, where they already know each other and have been working together for a while (and she's already engaged). So I'm not sure how long he had a crush on her.

Comment: @Walt That's completely irrelevant....Before Season 1 there was no show to begin with so how can one assume something before the show began?

Comment: 1. Because OP's asking for an *in universe* answer. Please re-read the question; 2. Because I'm not assuming anything. Please see my answer above. I've provided information from the *show itself* about events that happened prior to season 1.